# Bulk rename files in Unix with current date as suffix

Tags: linux, bash, unix, batch-rename

I am trying to bulk rename all the files in the current folder with date suffix:

```
rename 's/(.*)/$1_$(date +%F)/' *
```

But that command is renaming `info.txt` to `info.txt_1000 4 24 27 30 46 113 128 1000date +%F)`. I want the result to be `info.txt_2016-10-13`

Answer (score 3):

You want `$1` to be passed literally to `rename`, yet have `$(date +%F)` to be expanded by the shell. The latter won't happen when you use single quotes, only with double quotes. The solution is to use double quotes and escape `$1` so the shell doesn't expand it.

```
rename "s/(.*)/\$1_$(date +%F)/" *
```

Answer (score 1):

### Portable Posix shell solution

Since you said "in Unix" and the `rename` command isn't portable (it's actually a part of the perl package), here is a solution that should work in more environments:

```sh
for file in *; do mv "$file" "${file}_$( date +%F )"; done
```

This creates a loop and then moves each individual file to the new name.  Like the question, it uses `date +%F` via shell process substitution to insert the "full date" (YYYY-mm-dd).  Process substitution must use double quotes (`"`) and not single quotes (`'`) because single quotes shut off shell interpretations (this goes for variables as well), as noted in [John's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40032098/519360).

### Argument list too long

Your shell will complain if the directory has too many files in it, with an error like "Argument list too long."  This is because `*` expands to the contents of the directory, all of which become arguments to the command you're running.

To solve that, create a script and then feed it through `xargs` as follows:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
if [ -z "$1" ]; then set *; fi  # default to all files in curent directory
for file in "$@"; do mv "$file" "${file}_$( date +%F )"; done
```

Using `ls` to generate a file list isn't always wise for scripts (it can do weird things in certain contexts). Use `find` instead:

```sh
find . -type f -not -name '*_20??-??-??' -print0 |xargs -0 sh /path/to/script.sh
```

Note, that command is recursive (change that by adding `-maxdepth 1` after the dot).  `find` is extremely capable.  In this example, it finds all files (`-type f`) that do not match the shell [glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) `*_20??-??-??` (`*` matches any number of any characters, `?` matches exactly one of any character, so this matches `abc_2016-10-14` but not `abc_2016-10-14-def`).  This uses `find … -print0` and `xargs -0` to ensure spacing is properly preserved (instead of spaces, these use the null character as the delimiter).

You can also do this with perl `rename`:

```sh
find . -type f -not -name '*_20??-??-??' -print0 |xargs -0 \
  rename "s/(.*)/\$1_$( date +%F )/"
```